# programmatic constraint definition and redefine the default group

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I want to use a programmatic constraint definition to redefine the default group:

```
constraintMapping.type(User.class)
   .defaultGroupSequence(AlwaysCheck.class, User.class)
   .property("name", ElementType.FIELD)
   .constraint(
        new LengthDef().max(1)
        .groups(AlwaysCheck.class)
        .message("text"))
```

When I persist the object in the database the check is not happening.

The same constraint works when given in annotations:

```
@GroupSequence({AlwaysCheck.class, User.class})
public class User implements Serializable {
    //...
    @Length(max = 1, message = "text", groups = {AlwaysCheck.class})         
    private String name;
}
```

How can I express this as a program?

**SOLUTION**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
   ...
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>                                
       ...
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.factory">#{validator}</prop>                
        </props>
    </property>                
  </bean>
```

**UPDATE2 @Gunnar**

In Spring Context I create bean

```
       <bean id="validator" class="....LocalValidatorFactoryBeanOverride">          
           <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>                                  
           <property name="constraintMappingFactory" ref="constraintMappingFactoryComponent" />                    
       </bean>

     //...
     public class LocalValidatorFactoryBeanOverride extends SpringValidatorAdapterOverride
    implements ValidatorFactory, ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean {

   //UPDATE My constraint definition
   private ConstraintMappingFactory constraintMappingFactory;

   //..
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Configuration configuration = (this.providerClass != null ?
            Validation.byProvider(this.providerClass).configure() :
            Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure());

    MessageInterpolator targetInterpolator = this.messageInterpolator;
    if (targetInterpolator == null) {
        targetInterpolator = configuration.getDefaultMessageInterpolator();
    }
    configuration.messageInterpolator(new LocaleContextMessageInterpolator(targetInterpolator));

    if (this.traversableResolver != null) {
        configuration.traversableResolver(this.traversableResolver);
    }

    ConstraintValidatorFactory targetConstraintValidatorFactory = this.constraintValidatorFactory;
    if (targetConstraintValidatorFactory == null && this.applicationContext != null) {
        targetConstraintValidatorFactory =
                new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(this.applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
    }
    if (targetConstraintValidatorFactory != null) {
        configuration.constraintValidatorFactory(targetConstraintValidatorFactory);
    }

    if (this.mappingLocations != null) {
        for (Resource location : this.mappingLocations) {
            try {
                configuration.addMapping(location.getInputStream());
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot read mapping resource: " + location);
            }
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : this.validationPropertyMap.entrySet()) {
        configuration.addProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

            if(constraintMappingFactory != null) {

                if(configuration instanceof HibernateValidatorConfiguration) {

                    HibernateValidatorConfiguration hibernateValidatorConfiguration = (HibernateValidatorConfiguration) configuration;

                    ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = constraintMappingFactory.getConstraintMapping(hibernateValidatorConfiguration);                        
                    hibernateValidatorConfiguration.addMapping(constraintMapping);
                }                    
            }



    this.validatorFactory = configuration.buildValidatorFactory();                
    setTargetValidator(this.validatorFactory.getValidator());
}

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you adding the mapping you created when bootstrapping the validator factory? It needs to be done like so:

```
Validator validator = configuration.addMapping( constraintMapping )
    .buildValidatorFactory()
    .getValidator();
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Everything works except defaultGroupSequence.

Comment: Manually invoking a `Validator` configured with that mapping gives me the expected result. But I see you're expecting this definition to be applied upon persisting. How are you triggering validation in this case? Is this via the default life-cycle validation triggered by JPA? How are you passing your configured `Validator` instance then? Are you saying that the programmatically configured @Length constraint is applied?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not use JPA. In the session / transaction Hibernate I load the User object from DB and set the field name - setName ("12345"). When closing the transaction (declaratively Spring) I expect that I will get an exception. This is not happening. If I call manually validator.validate(user, AlwaysCheck.Class), I get the correct validation error. If I use the annotation-based approach (not programmatic), when transaction closing I get the right exception, without need for manual checking.

Comment: Feeling that the programmatic approach does not change the default group, while persist object and validation mechanism (EventListiner right?) use  Default.class group.

Comment: So how are you setting up the validator used upon transaction commit? You need to make sure that this instance is bootstrapped using the constraint mapping you configured. A custom version of Spring's `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` may be helpful for that (assuming that's how you obtain your validator).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
I added material in the post with a question. 
Everything works that the manual validate (validator.validate(user, AlwaysCheck.Class)). 
Except override the default group.

Comment: Maybe I did not set validor object that I use in Spring, as the default validator for Hibernate?

Comment: Yes, that's what I think as well. By default, Hibernate will bootstrap its own validator factory. You can pass in a `ValidatorFactory` instance through the "javax.persistence.validation.factory" (also when using the classic API and not JPA). I'm not totally sure how you'd do this using Spring, but I believe you can access the `Configuration` used by `LocalSessionFactoryBean` (or have your own variant of the latter).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I have a mistake in last comment. I not override constraintValidatorFactory, I set custom constraintMappingFactory. If you look at code for method afterPropertiesSet, it is the same as in the Hibernate Validator documentation section 5.1. Configuration and ValidatorFactory.

Comment: I need to replace the default validator object which use on pre-persist/update on my validator object from LocalValidatorFactoryBeanOverride. How to do it?